# Is there a way to extract value from numbers with bracket within text file?

Tags: python, split

I have a very basic question but I did not find any "beautiful" solution  on the internet. All I want is to extract number from a line where there are string and bracket.
For instance, I have an output text file as follows :

```
test: [1, 50, 200]
```

I want to extract the values 1, 50 and 200 in order to make a numpy array of these numbers.

The issue has been already solved with some split and strip but I do not find this solution very elegant.

Comment: On stackoverflow you are supposed to show what you've tried so far so we can help you.

Comment: @JohnColeman I had to put 2 split, 1 strip and 2 replace so it is a bit more than a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a very naive regex:

```
import numpy as np
import re

nums = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', 'test: [1, 50, 200]'))
print(np.array([n for n in nums]))
# [  1  50 200]
```

Another alternative will be to use a regex to extract the entire list then use `literal_eval`:

```
import numpy as np
import re
from ast import literal_eval

li = re.search(r'(\[.*\])', 'test: [1, 50, 200]').group()
print(np.array(literal_eval(li)))
# [  1  50 200]
```

Comment: Perfect ! It was the kind of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`ast.literal_eval` gives one solution:

```
import ast
s = 'test: [1, 50, 200]'
ast.literal_eval(s.split(':')[1].strip())

#evaluates to [1, 50, 200]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably actually use something involving splits or regex to have some error checking and security --- to make sure that there is nothing malicious hidden in the input. But you could do something like this.

I'll suppose that you have your line of text in a string variable `line`. Then you can do

```py
from ast import literal_eval
line = "test: [1, 50, 200]"    # or whatever your line is
array = literal_eval(line.partition(":")[2].strip())
```

But be cautious, because running `eval` on uncertain input is dangerous.

Comment: No, do not use `eval`. Use `literal_eval` that verifies the input for you.

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, that is a good suggestion. I'll edit that in.